# radio button empty in first row of jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a problem in my DataTables that radio button in first row is always empty. But if I see it using firebug radio button option is **checked**.

I have searched and find that it is bug in DataTables. I have read all many other solutions but no one works for me. Does any one have solution for this problem?

I am using following
**RadioButton**

```
 <input type="radio"
  name="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']?>" value="1"
  <?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1']=='1'){ ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>
  class="<?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1']=='1'){ ?>checked<?php } ?>"
  id="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']?>">Yes

 <input type="radio" 
  name="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']?>" value="0"
  <?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1']=='0'){ ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>
  class="<?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1']=='0'){ ?>checked<?php } ?>"
  id="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']?>">No
```

And I used following jquery tweak in DataTables code with **fnDrawCallback** function but it is also not working.

```
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
                  $('.checked input:radio:checked').attr("checked","checked");
                },
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

First, what kind of PHP script is that? Could you please try to check this script below if it'll work:

```
 <input type="radio"
  name="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']; ?>" value="1"
  <?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1'] == 1){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
  class="<?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1'] == 1){ echo "checked"; } ?>"
  id="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']; ?>">Yes

 <input type="radio" 
  name="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']; ?>" value="0"
  <?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1'] == 0){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>
  class="<?php if($patent['Patent']['review_1'] == 0){ echo "checked"; } ?>"
  id="<?php echo $patent['Patent']['id']; ?>">No
```

Comment: I'm sorry to your issue about *“jquery tweak”*, by now, I couldn't guess that part..

Comment: have you ever used datatables.net?. Then you can answer this question otherwise you can't .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick solution to it. Basically, you need to set the Radio button as checked via JS/jQuery after the DataTable is Applied.

Below link is used for Extension of Demo Here is the fiddle:

```
//JQuery Code

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#department_permissions_table').dataTable();  
} // code to set the value as checked.  

$("#deptartment_permission[2]").attr('checked', 'checked'); );

//JS Code  

radiobtn = document.getElementById("theid"); radiobtn.checked = true;
```